# Выпадающее меню в css

Tags: css

Как в этом меню можно добавить пункты например 3, 4 пункта чтобы открывались при наведении мыши.Какие свойства нужна прописать в css ,и куда добавить пункты

```
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Квартиры</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Новостройки</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Нежилые помещения</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Дома и коттеджи</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавляем список `ul li ... /ul` в нутрь `li` после `a`. Стили:

```
ul ul {display:none;}

ul li {position:relative;}

li:hover > ul {display:block; position:absolute; [top:[[высота родительского li]]px;]/[left:[[ширина родительского li]]px;]}
```